# Database server version is different than the version of SQL Server I have installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm opening up SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

When I connect to my database server, it says the version is 9.0.2047. But when I connect to my analysis server and report server, they are both version 10.50.1600.1.

How can I change my database server so that it is running version 10.50.1600.1?

Comment: Run the instance upgrade wizard in 2008R2? 9.xxxx means it's SQL 2005 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the SSMS Object Explorer, from the "Connect dropdown > Database Engine..." item, you can choose from all your available database servers.

It seems like you have different versions of SQL Server installed alongside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall SQL Server 2005, and install SQL Server 2008 R2.

[Here's a nice website with versions for you](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).